# Prolog: Difference relation between two objects

Tags: prolog

I will be **honest** and preface this by saying it is homework, but I desperately need help.

I am new to Prolog, coming from C++ and Javascript and no matter how hard I try, I'm just not getting it.

What I am supposed to do is to be able to find the difference between two dates (assuming non leap year).

Basically I have a knowledge base with information laid out like:

```
   object(A, B).
   object(A, B).
    ...
```

where A represents month and B represents total days of the month.
(eg. object(1, 31).)

The expression I am supposed to use for input is this:
 Difference(Object(A,B), object(A,B), N).
(N = difference between the objects).

I have tried a few different things (and I know this isn't on the right track) and haven't been able to get further then:

```
difference(object(A,B), object(A,B),N):-
    days(M,D), days(M,D),
    Y = 365-D,
    N is Y.
```

I don't understand how to make the two objects register as individual things that I can manipulate and therefore continue with the problem.

Can someone please please please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Homework Question (AS REQUESTED).
Assume the presence of the days relation that describes how many days are in
each calendar month of a non-leap year.

```
days(1,31).
days(2,28).
```

(and so on).

The structure dateObject(M, D) describes a date. For example dateObject(6,5) would denote the 5th of June.
Write the relation difference(From, To, N), where N is the number of days between starting
date From and finishing date To. The From date is not included in the count. For
example:

```
?- difference(dateobject(2,1),dateobject(2,2),N).
N = 1.
```

If the day or month values in a date are invalid (e.g. dateobject(4,31), dateobject(13,1) then the
value of N returned should be -1. If the From date is later than To then the -1 error value should also be returned for N.

Comment: What does the "difference between the objects" mean?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "make the two objects register as individual things that I can manipulate"?

Comment: @Enigmativity Basically the objects represent days in a months:
days(1, 31).

difference(dateobject(4,30), dateobject(5,15),N).

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What does the "difference between the objects" mean?

Comment: @Enigmativity the difference is the number of days between the two date objects.

Comment: @TheLeftRight Have you gone through a tutorial?

Comment: @jcolemang I've been trying to understand stuff from my coursework, I've watched the simple engineers stuff on prolog on YouTube, i've gone over everything I can find and even searched through stack overflow and not found anything to point me where I need to go... Or I have and haven't understood it...

Comment: @TheLeftRight - Can you post the exact homework question/s you've been asked? What you've got in your question just doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @TheLeftRight - You also haven't answered my second question.

Comment: @Enigmativity I've edited my post to contain the homework question at the bottom which should answer your questions I hope and it should make more sense.

Comment: @TheLeftRight - That is a whole lot clearer. Can you see how much better that is than your original question?

Comment: @Enigmativity  honestly yes and I do apologise for the poor wording of my question, as stated I am really struggling with prolog. However I didn't want to ask a homework question directly, I feel bad enough having to ask for help for school work as it is.

Comment: I'm sorry, and I almost never do this, but "give me the codez" is not a valid question format for SO, which is: present your code, your test call, the expected and actual output and/or error messages, and ask a specific, focused question. And an answer with not a word of explanation or even a comment is not a valid format for an SO answer, when the asker clearly lacks any command of Prolog's basics (no, "testing" is not a learning technique). So I'm going to *have* to downvote both the Q and the A. If either is edited/improved, ping me and I'll re-vote on it. @Enigmativity

Comment: @WillNess, I did ask to be pointed in the right direction. As stated in the question I am new to prolog. I should also clarify that while it is interesting, I will probably never use prolog again as I am mainly do web development and build games in c++ and java.

I am very appreciative of Enigmativity for providing a solution to the problem, which I have modified a bit to suit my style better.


I will keep your comments in mind in my next couple of questions as I have almost finished my homework but there are a couple of things that I can't work out sadly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve --- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @WillNess - I do try to avoid explanation in my answers for homework questions. I think the OP should take the time to study how it works before they try to hand in someone's work.

Comment: And I have been messing around with the code quite a bit (which I am once again very appreciative of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a really bad solution - I'm sure someone smarter than me will come up with something better.

```
?- difference(dateobject(1,28),dateobject(6,1),N),write(N),nl.

days(1,31).
days(2,28).
days(3,31).
days(4,30).
days(5,31).
days(6,30).
days(7,31).
days(8,31).
days(9,30).
days(10,31).
days(11,30).
days(12,31).

daysbetween(M,FD,M,TD,N) :- !, N is TD - FD.
daysbetween(FM,FD,TM,TD,N) :-
    days(FM,D),
    FM2 is FM + 1,
    daysbetween(FM2,FD,TM,TD,N2),
    N is D + N2.

difference(dateobject(FM,FD),dateobject(TM,TD),N) :-
    TM >= FM,
    FD >= 1,
    days(FM,FDM),
    FD =< FDM,
    TD >= 1,
    days(TM,TDM),
    TD =< TDM,
    daysbetween(FM,FD,TM,TD,N),
    N > 0,
    !.
difference(_,_,-1).
```

Comment: I will test it soon and get back to you. Don't say it's bad though, it's way better then anything I have come up with and you have no idea how much I appreciate all the help you've given me here. Will test once I get back to my computer

Comment: Sir, you are a literal legend.